# The css code for underline does not work, and the css code doesnt work with the html/

Tags: html, css, underline

I am new to html and css, I just desined sample website on xd adobe. image of it is attached. The html works but when I am working on the css part is not workink, I does not shown on the website. I am coding at a scss file and not css file. I will appreciate any help! You can see I wrote on the css file that the logo should be without underLine but still its not working

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");
body {
  background: #F2F2F2;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background: white;
  padding: 1em;
  .logo2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10em;
  }
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>JustFly</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="logo2" href="#">JustFly</a>
      <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="images/menu.svg" alt="Hamburger Menu">

      <nav>
        <img id="mobile-exit" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="images/exit.svg" alt="Hamburger Menu">

        <ul class="primary-nav">
          <li class="current"> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">FAQ</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Pricing</a> </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="secondary-nav">
          <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
          <li class="GoPremiumBtn"><a href="#">Buy Now</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section class="hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col">
        <h1 class="head">Fly Like Never Before.</h1>
      </div>
      <img id="mainImage" class="mainImage" src="images/icons8-fighter-jet-96.png" alt="Fighet Plane Image">

    </div>


  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Design in XD :

[image]

Code Image:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: You're writing **S**CSS not **CSS**

Comment: Can you expend a little more please? I followd a youtube course

Answer (score 0):

Try `a.logo2:link, a:logo2:visited` as a selector for that CSS rule. That should be more specific than the browser default `a:link` and `a:visited` and overrule them.

Comment: Can you be a liitle more specific? I'm new to this and did not really understand. I appreciate it very much

Comment: Where your CSS rule starts with `.logo2 { ... }`, replace `.logo2 ` with `a.logo2:link, a:logo2:visited`

Comment: a.logo2:link, a:logo2:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    font-size: 10em;
    }

Comment: The output is the same.